# How to redirect extension less URL using HttpHandlers/ HttpModules

Tags: asp.net, webforms, routes, httphandler, httpmodule

I want to add dynamic routing or redirect to website where one can utilize multiple URL for the same page. I want to implement dynamically same using Global.asax, but i am not able to find much help regarding the same topic.

Below are some sample url and Dummy Table structure with data that holds multiple url for same page.

Can we add dynamically routes to `global.asax` file

Suppose if I have multiple routes for the same page for example

- http://website.com/about
- http://website.com/en/about
- http://website.com/en/about-us

While my actual URL for the page is like `http://website.com/en/about-us`.

My question now is: is there a way I can dynamically define these routes in `global.asax` file  in such a way that it reads the URL entered by users like `http://website.com/about` and then compares it with database table and redirects it to the correct page which is `http://website.com/en/about-us`?

**If option A** is not possible then how can i achieve same using `HttpHandlers/HttpModules`. [This link show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737886/httphandler-redirect/2737956#2737956) configuration of HttpHandlers but not the actual code for handler

Taking into consideration following Table Structure:

```
Id  URL_Name    URL                                 Actual_URL                              Page_Handler
1   Home        http://website.com/                 http://website.com/                     Default.aspx
2   About Us    http://website.com/about            http://website.com/en/about-us          About.aspx
3   About Us    http://website.com/about-us         http://website.com/en/about-us          About.aspx
4   About Us    http://website.com/en/about         http://website.com/en/about-us          About.aspx
5   Contact     http://website.com/contact          http://website.com/en/contact-us        Contact.aspx
6   Contact     http://website.com/en/contact       http://website.com/en/contact-us        Contact.aspx
```

I want this for **asp.net webform** based website

Comment: You asked this same question yesterday. Did you try the approach I suggested ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Does your IIS version / ASP.NET version support integrated mode application pools? If so, then you wouldn't need HttpModules/HttpHandlers, you could simply use ASP.NET routing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx#routes) to route different urls to the same webform